# Cache page without the navbar. User log-in/logout system doesn't update at all (MVC)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, caching, cache-control, outputcache

I'm trying to cache a page without the navbar of the page.
When i cache the page its all works fine but I get unwanted behavior.

Explanation:

When I cache the index page for example, the navbar is also cached so if the user press the log-in button and log-on, the user redirect to the same page (Index) and the log-in doesn't take affect (the user name and the log out button doesn't  appear), the log-in and register buttons still shows, its a problem.

This is my code:

**Home Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=(60*60))]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Can I do Vary by something to prevent it ?

Comment: Use Donut-Caching solution like https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching

Comment: @haim770 thanks for the help but I need to NOT cache a partial view from my view, not html.action, There are any workaround ?

Comment: You'll have to exclude the navigation bar from the caching process somehow. The other approach you can try is to write some Javascript (on the client side) to show/hide the relevant parts based on the current user authentication state.

Comment: So the question is how can I use the @Html.Action approach (in order to use the donut cache) for the rendering of the partial view of the log-in ?

Comment: Yes. You can see some examples in my first link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the solution using "haim770" guidelines.

The solution using the "Donut-Caching" (https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching)

1.first I get the "Donut Caching from the NuGet Packages.

2.I switched in the _layout.cshtml page the line : `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` with  `@Html.Action("partialView", true)`

3.Than I build an Action inside the Account controller called "partialView" that return the view I wanted, like this :

```
public ActionResult partialView()
    {
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
    }
```

4.After it I decorated the Action that return the index page with

> [DonutOutputCache(Duration=(60*60))]

like this:

```
  [DonutOutputCache(Duration=(60*60))]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And you done, Thanks again to Haim(Chaim).

Comment: Thanks, but i see that performance is much less than the original output cache attribute